# thread id behavior in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was going through the new support for multi -threading that is present in c++ 0x (C++11).

So there is a unique identifier of type std::thread:id for each thread.

Consider the below sample program:

```
void hello_world()
{
  std::cout<<"hello_world \n";
}

int main()
{

    std::cout<<"Main thread id is "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<"\n";

    std::thread t(hello_world);

    std::cout<<"Child thread id is ";
    std::cout<<t.get_id()<<"\n";
    t.join();
}
```

I got a sample output as follows:

Main thread id is  140502917359424

Child thread id is 140502900623104

hello_world

The thread id of the main thread from my sample output is greater than that of the child thread id.

Are the thread id's totally independent of the their time of start?

If not : Is there a way to differentiate whether a thread T1 started earlier than  thread T2 from just the thread id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::thread::get_id()` is just an arbitrary value, its only property is that it is guaranteed to be unique for each thread currently running (but when a thread ends its id can be reused).

In order to tell which thread started first you'll just have to do it yourself : eg. maintain a counter and somehow associate the value with the thread, either by wrapping both in a class, or passing the value to the thread function, or using Thread Local Storage, ... You get the idea.

I can't think of any C++ or system facility that does it for you, maybe because it's usually pointless to know the relative creation order of a bunch of threads. You just fire them up and let them do their job.

Answer (score 3):

There can't be a strict relation between thread id and thread creation. Threads are created by other threads so this creation potentially happens in parallel. Usually the thread id is just a (reinterpreted) pointer to the thread's internal state, so you should not try to interpret anything into it.